# Bitcoind stops downloading the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

I have bitcoind running on Ubuntu 16.4 VPS.
The problem is that it just randomly stops downloading the blockchain and when i run

```
bitcoin-cli getblockcount
```

it returns in begining the block count - 165572 and after 10 minutes its look like its crashed and show me 0.

any ideas?